# UITableView does not scroll correctly (or not at all)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to scroll in a UITableView, while a keyboard is showing. I resize the TableView, so that it is not covered by the keyboard. I overwrote the textFieldShouldReturn function to skip to the next UITextField in my UITableView, and also scroll to the next field. Here is the code I use:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.prefTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSString *nextRowKey = [preferences nextRowKeyAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (nextRowKey != nil) {
        tagBeingEdited = textField.tag + 1;
        NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1
                                                    inSection:indexPath.section];

        [self.prefTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath
                                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                          animated:YES];
        //[self.prefTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath 
        //                                animated:YES
        //                          scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        if ([[self.prefTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath] == YES) {
            [[self.prefTableView viewWithTag:tagBeingEdited] becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    } else {
        isEditing = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

However, my view *never* scrolls. Or if I manually have scrolled the view, it will go back to the top. Why?

**Note:** I only use one of scrollToRowAtIndexPath and selectRowAtIndexPath. I just put both of them there, since I first tried one and then the other.

Comment: Is your view controller a subclass of UIViewController? You get better support for keyboard+tables working well together if you subclass UITableViewController instead. It would handle the resizing of the UITableView for you, for example.

Comment: It was a subclass of UITableViewController. The bahaviour was the same as now, though. I changed it to UIViewController after some other hints. This is the declaration of my view controller:


    @interface PreferencesController : UIViewController 
        <UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>

Comment: I tried a little bit more, added more rows, and enabled the cells to show their selection. The selection progresses on correctly, but the view scrolls almost arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@occulus is right that UITableViewController automatically handles resizing when the keyboard appears. If you want that behavior with a subclass of UIViewController, you need extra work.

The following link from Cocoa with love has an example of doing this.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html

Comment: Ok, I isolated the problem. My UITableView and UITableViewController pair are a subview of another UIViewController derived object. I manually load my own class and use addSubView to add it to the main UIView. If I leave out this intermediate class, scrolling and resizing works automatically. However, I want to have that intermediate class, since I add a heading and a button to dismiss the view... Let's see if I can make them work together. :)